# MVC 5 Browser link causes "blank spam"

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, browser-link

I'm using VS2013 Ultimate with a MVC5 project. 
Whenever I launch my current project, there is a "spam" of blank pages in the solution explorer under Overview (see image at end of post).

It has to do with browser link, when I turn that off, the blank pages disappear. All pages are called "blank" and appear every 6 seconds when browser link does its arterySignalR thing.

Some of the blank pages are empty and some contain:

```
jQuery18206395680124171028_1415778808249({"C":"d-F1AD72A7-B,0|C,9|D,0","M":[
{\"name\":\"sys.callback\",\"args\":[6,[]],\"callbackId\":-1}"]});
```

or

```
jQuery18206395680124171028_1415778808249({"C":"d-F1AD72A7-B,0|C,D|D,0","M":[]});
```

If my project has been running for an hour, there are literally hundreds of these.

See this image for the top of the list (it goes on and on with blank):
[image]

So I can turn off browser link to resolve this but I like its functionality. Any ideas?

Comment: No solution, but the workaround I'm using is to enable the Silverlight debugger under project properties. This disables JavasScript debugging and therefor no more spam. Sadly no more JavaScript debugging either.

Comment: OK, thanks. Not really a work-around for me

Comment: This happened when I updated Web Grease. The new project had version 1, I updated to 1.6 and the blank files started showing up.